# How load image trough ajax with personal http headers in javascript (sencha touch 2)

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I'm working on a sencha touch app and I have a form whose need load an jpeg/image and required some headers in the request headers. **Simply it can't be load at traditional way, or I get a 403 (forbidden) error.**

I try many ways but without success so I think that ajax is the solution. Ajax can load binary data?

*Somebody knows if it's possible do that?*

Or is it just impossible and I must do it in another way?

Thanks

Comment: Have you found solution to this issue? I have the exact problem. URL of the image, i'm trying to load is in store, and i'm trying to load it in itemTpl.


`code`
itemTpl: <img src={image} />,
`code`


And i always get 403 forbidden.

I also noticed in RequestHeader that Referer is set to 'http://10.20.30.43/nezavisne/'. Maybe that is the issue, because when loading image via browser Referer is not set.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this stackoverflow thread might be of help: [Set a request header in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268673/set-request-header-in-javascript)

Anyway, please consider using the **setRequestHeader** method. Check under section *4.7.2* on http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/

Comment: El problema es que mediante XMLHttpRequest no se puede cargar una imagen directamente o al menos no sé algún truco como hacerlo.

Comment: @DavidV el problema persiste? O encontraste solución?

Comment: I believe you can request the file as an XMLHttpRequest and then encode the response into base64 and use a dataURI to display the image