# Can an iframe be loaded as if the content was rendered by a different browser?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I am currently creating a new version of a website that uses a third party service that can only be accessed through an iframe. This service exclusively works on Internet Explorer (not on Edge) in compatibility mode (and with certain security options set), while the new website is developed with more modern browsers in mind (mainly Chrome).

Is there any way to insert an iframe into the page, and **make the iframe load its content with IE's engine** even though the page containing it has been loaded in Chrome?

I'm not talking about the "user agent" field in the request header (as discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12845445/load-iframe-content-with-different-user-agent)), I'm talking about rendering the response with a different browser's engine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Load iframe content with different user agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12845445/load-iframe-content-with-different-user-agent)

Comment: @Rikin that's just about the user agent communicated to the server in the request headers, not the actual engine used to render the response

Comment: Yeah you cant run different engine for iframe in a browser.

Answer (score 4):

No, there isn't.

Not even if the computer has Internet Explorer installed.

Comment: I was afraid so. I'll wait a couple days out of remote hope and then I'll accept your answer

Answer (score 0):

iframes dont have a support for browser option selection. so this requirement cant be fulfilled. there is one plugin called ietab but its only for development purpose, which runes ie in chrome browser.