# Custom User Agent with Iframes

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, google-chrome-extension

Yes, I have read [Load iframe content with different user agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12845445/load-iframe-content-with-different-user-agent) but I do not understand how to implement it correctly/it does not work

I am trying to create a Iframe with  a custom user agent inside a chrome extension, and this is my current code (from other tutorials/answers)

```js
function setUserAgent(window, userAgent) {
    if (window.navigator.userAgent != userAgent) {
        var userAgentProp = { get: function () { return userAgent; } };
        try {
            Object.defineProperty(window.navigator, 'userAgent', userAgentProp);
        } catch (e) {
            window.navigator = Object.create(navigator, {
                userAgent: userAgentProp
            });
        }
    }
}
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
document.querySelector('iframe').contentWindow, 'Test User Agent';
});
```

```html
<title>Title</title>
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/ico" sizes="16x16">
<iframe src="https://www.whatsmyua.info/" frameborder="0" style="overflow:hidden;height:100%;width:100%" height="100%" width="100%"></iframe>
<script src='index.js'>
</script>
```

For Some reason the user agent is not working, as shown by the page that loads.

Comment: What should I make it match? because I only want to change the User Agent for certain windows, not all tabs (or even all of my extensions windows) but the match requires a URL

Answer (score 1):

You need to [insert that code into the page context using a content script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9517879).

**1a. Inject a content script**

It can be injected programmatically from your extension page into the iframe.

manifest.json

```
"permissions": ["webNavigation"]
```

index.js:

```js
chrome.tabs.getCurrent(tab => {
  chrome.webNavigation.onCommitted.addListener(function onCommitted(info) {
    if (info.tabId === tab.id) {
      chrome.webNavigation.onCommitted.removeListener(onCommitted);
      chrome.tabs.executeScript({
        frameId: info.frameId,
        file: 'content.js',
        runAt: 'document_start',
      });
    }
  }, {
    url: [{urlEquals: document.querySelector('iframe').src}],
  });
});
```

**1b. Declare a content script**

Note that the previous approach may theoretically allow some of the iframe's inline scripts in its `<head>` to run first. In that case you'll have to add a dummy URL parameter to the iframe `src` (for example `https://example.org/page/page?foobar`) and use [declarative matching](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#declaratively) in manifest.json:

```
"content_scripts": [{
  "matches": ["*://example.org/*?foobar*"],
  "all_frames": true,
  "run_at": "document_start",
  "js": ["content.js"]
}],
```

**2. Add a page script**

To run our code immediately let's run it via textContent. We're not using a separate file for page code because that would put it into a queue where it could run after the currently pending page scripts.

content.js:

```js
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.textContent = '(' + function() {
  Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'userAgent', {
    get() {
      return 'Test User Agent';
    },
  });
} + ')();';
(document.head||document.documentElement).appendChild(script);
script.remove();
```

Comment: The browser console's error message showed that the `chrome.tabs.getCurrent` function is returning `undefined`. The `chrome.tabs` API is not available in the current context.

Comment: @Oo'-, this answer is using the question's index.js which is a part of the action popup. Since you have a different setup please open a new question.