# I am trying to create an `iframe` with a fake user agent string in pure HTML page, to simulate the local site

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, user-agent

Of course that I have read these following questions:

- [Custom User Agent with Iframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63729183/custom-user-agent-with-iframes) : the most recent question, but it is designed for the Chrome extension that @fredthedoggy wanted to create. I did not intend to create a Chrome extension. I intend to write a pure HTML page, but running the server.
- [Load iframe content with different user agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12845445/load-iframe-content-with-different-user-agent) : @aero-wang’s answer didn't answer with both `userAgent` and @mahmonir-bakhtiyari’`'user-agent'`. Same problem of @fredthedoggy's question.

I am creating a pure HTML page in which I created the smartwatch simulators to simulate the local site to detect the fake user agent string in JavaScript to add a new CSS link. Here are my current codes:

- `simulator.html`:

````html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Smartwatches with round and squircle displays design responsive</title>
        <style>
            iframe
            {
                background-color: antiquewhite;
                border: 0;
            }

            .round
            {
                width: 300px;
                height: 300px;
            }

            .sqirc
            {
                -webkit-clip-path: url(#squircle);
                                clip-path: url(#squircle);
                width: 300px;
                height: 335px;
            }

            .round
            {
                border-radius: 50%;
            }

            .result
            {
                align-items: center;
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: row;
                margin-top: 20px;
            }

            .result label
            {
                margin-right: 10px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Squircle display -->
        <iframe allow="geolocation 'self'" class="sqirc" name="Apple Watch Series 6" sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin allow-popups allow-pointer-lock allow-orientation-lock allow-modals allow-forms" src="https://www.google.com/search?igu=1"></iframe>

        <!-- Round display -->
        <iframe allow="geolocation 'self'" class="round" name="Samsung Galaxy Watch 5" sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin allow-popups allow-pointer-lock allow-orientation-lock allow-modals allow-forms" src="https://www.google.com/search?igu=1"></iframe>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        // Getting the elements
        var url = document.getElementById('url');

        // I use only the keyboard to press Enter to update the URL
        url.addEventListener('keyup', function(e)
        {
            if (e.keyCode == 13)
            {
                update();
            }
        });

        window.onload = function() 
        {
            function setUserAgent(window, userAgent) 
            {
                if (window.navigator.userAgent != userAgent) 
                {
                    var userAgentProp = { get: function () { return userAgent; } };
                    try 
                    {
                            Object.defineProperty(window.navigator, 'userAgent', userAgentProp);
                    } 
                    
                    catch (e) 
                    {
                            window.navigator = Object.create(navigator, 
                            {
                                    userAgent: userAgentProp
                            });
                    }
                }
            }

            // Load the user agent strings
            var sqircUserAgent = 'atc/1.0 watchOS/8 model/Watch6,2 hwp/t8301 build/18T567 (6; dt:226)';
            var roundUserAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 11; SAMSUNG SM-R860) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) SamsungBrowser/2.0.10 Chrome/102.0.5005.125 Mobile Safari/537.36';

            var sqirc = document.querySelector('.sqirc');
            var round = document.querySelector('.round');
            setUserAgent(rect.contentWindow, rectUserAgent);
            setUserAgent(sqirc.contentWindow, sqircUserAgent);
            setUserAgent(round.contentWindow, roundUserAgent);
        };

        function update()
        {
            var urlValue = url.value;
            // Updating the simulators settings
            var rect = document.querySelector('.rect');

            rect.src = urlValue;
            var sqirc = document.querySelector('.sqirc');

            sqirc.src = urlValue;
            var round = document.querySelector('.round');
            round.src = urlValue;
        }

        // Updating after the user agent strings have been loaded
        update();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```
````

- `local_site.html`:

  ```html
  <script>
    var isSamsungWatch = /SAMSUNG SM-R860/i.test(navigator.userAgent);

    if (isSamsungWatch) 
    {
      console.log("This is a Samsung Galaxy Watch device.");
    } 

    else 
    {
      console.log("This is not a Samsung Galaxy Watch device.");
    }
  </script>
  ```

The result said that, in the simulators, they were not Samsung Galaxy Watch device. I tested the commands in the console:

```html
var sq = document.querySelector('.round')
sq.contentWindow.navigator.userAgent
```

It gave a wrong user agent string. It is my computer's user agent string. For this reason, I do not know why @aero-wang's or @wOxxOm's suggestions do nor work my for my project.

Comment: I believe the solutions in those questions only work if you add the `src` to the iframe dynamically. If the `src` is in the <iframe> tag, it will already have loaded the URL with the default user agent before you modify it.

Comment: The solution will also affect what happens if the iframe loads other documents after you modify the user agent.

Comment: @Barmar You are right. Exact :)

Comment: May I ask what leads you to believe that (non-browser-extension) JS could ever change the `User-Agent` header on outbound document requests? Because they can't, and they never could, for what should be extremely obvious reasons. While JS can overwrite the `navigator.userAgent` DOM property value, that only affects scripts running in the same page/script-context, and it has zero effect on document-level requests, nor XHR/`fetch` requests. Besides, the `User-Agent` header is deprecated now.

Comment: I made the code dynamic again, and the result was still the same with both `userAgent` and `user-agent`. I really do not know why.