# Make an <iframe> think the device is not a mobile phone (even if it is)

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, responsive-design

As [discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39625513/soundcloud-embedded-player-on-mobile#) the user experience of the Soundcloud embedded player is really poor on mobile devices (for those who don't have or don't want the app), because it requires a) a very precise tap with finger on the small "Listen in browser"  b) one more tap to pause because autoplay doesn't work correctly on some devices, c) one tap to play:

[image]

Question: is there a way to make a page loaded inside an `<iframe>` "think" the device is not a mobile phone?

I'm looking for a technique that doesn't require to install a browser add-on to fake the user agent, because I can't ask every visitor of my website to install such a browser extension.

Is there a solution like this:

```
<html>
<body>
<script> 
// Fake user agent for the next iframe
// No no, we're not on a mobile device ;) 
</script>
<iframe width="100%" height="166" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/271188615&amp;color=ff5500&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_comments=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;show_reposts=false"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you looked into whether SoundCloud offers a "desktop version" that you can toggle from your mobile device? If they do, you could compare the URLs of the mobile version vs. forced-desktop version and figure out what parameters are needed to trigger the latter. (For example, Facebook has a URL parameter called `?m2w` - mobile to web - which triggers the desktop site on mobile.)

Comment: @JonUleis i haven't found a desktop only version

Answer (score 0):

This question was answered on 2 different occasions already. Go to this post:

[Fake User Agent for iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12057890/fake-user-agent-for-iframe)