# XHR setRequestHeader is manipulating access-control-request vs adding a custom header

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to add a completely custom HTTP header - in this case as an example - Header=dog with value=cat.  When I run this, in stead of getting a new header, it appends dog to the values in access-control-request-headers?  How do I get a new custom header?

Code:

```
            HR = new XMLHttpRequest();
            HR.onload = function (e) {
                    }
            HR.open("GET", URI);
            HR.setRequestHeader('dog', 'cat');
            HR.send();
```

Request headers as viewed through Chrome developer tools:

```
access-control-request-headers: origin, dog
access-control-request-method: GET
origin: http://localhost:8888
accept-encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.8
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.95 Safari/537.36
:path: /
accept: */*
:version: HTTP/1.1
cache-control: max-age=0
referer: http://localhost:8888/x.html
:scheme: https
:method: OPTIONS
Response Headersview source
access-control-allow-headers:origin, dog
access-control-allow-methods:OPTIONS
access-control-allow-origin:*
access-control-max-age:300
cache-control:private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
content-length:0
```

Comment: see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268673/set-request-header-in-javascript