# pass parameters from angularjs to rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I have 2 project: 1.rails project. 2.angularjs project.
In the rails project, I have a `widget` model that I create by `scaffold`. Now I want get widget data from angularjs project and post data to rails controller.
for this, I create 2 `textfield` in angularjs project, when I complete the field, I post the data by below code:

`app.js`:

```
var app = angular.module("app",[]);

app.controller("AppCtrl", function($http){
    app = this;
    $http.get("http://localhost:3000/widgets.json")
        .success(function(data){
            console.log(data)
            app.peaple = data;
        })
    app.addWidget = function (widget){
        $http.post("http://localhost:3000/widgets",widget)
    }
})
```

`index.html`:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="app.widget.name">
<input type="text" ng-model="app.widget.price">
<input type="button" ng-click="app.addWidget(app.widget)">
```

In rails project, I have below code:
`widgets_controller.rb`:

```
skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token  
  # POST /widgets
  # POST /widgets.json
  def create
    @widget = Widget.new(widget_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @widget.save
        format.html { redirect_to @widget, notice: 'Widget was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @widget }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @widget.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

`config/routes.rb`:

```
match '/widgets' => 'widgets#create', via: :options
```

When I send widget data from angularjs project to rails controller, I get below error in server log:

```
Started OPTIONS "/widgets" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-19 14:29:20 +0430
Processing by WidgetsController#create as */*
Completed 400 Bad Request in 0ms

ActionController::ParameterMissing (param not found: widget):
  app/controllers/widgets_controller.rb:75:in `widget_params'
  app/controllers/widgets_controller.rb:29:in `create'
```

and below error in chrome browsers:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request) http://localhost:3000/widgets
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:3000/widgets. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:63343' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Where is the problem? How can fix this errors?

Answer (score 0):

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:3000/widgets. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:63343' is therefore not allowed access.
```

This message explains what to do. Add following header to your request and response

Also check this question, it might be answered here
[Set a request header in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268673/set-a-request-header-in-javascript)

Comment: I get this error when I use `GET` method too, For this, I add below line to `application_controller.rb` and error is fixed:`headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST, GET, OPTIONS'
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = %w{Origin Accept Content-Type X-Requested-With X-CSRF-Token}.join(',')
    headers['Access-Control-Max-Age'] = "1728000"`.

but for post method, I get this error, My question is how can I fixed this error?

Comment: updated my answer, try to set headers when you do post