# response not getting with the header in javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm new to AJAX and I have the following code:

```
function get_filesize(url, callback) {
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("HEAD", url, true); 

xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == this.DONE) {
        callback(parseInt(xhr.getResponseHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials')));
    }
};
xhr.send();
}

get_filesize("http://fileraja.com/download/?songURL=./Tamil/K/Kaththi_160kbps/Pakkam_Vanthu-StarMusiQ.Com.mp3", function(size) {
var estimatedtime = (new Date().getTime())/size;
var time = new Date(estimatedtime);
console.log(time.getHours() + ":" + time.getMinutes() + ":" + time.getSeconds());
});
```

When I run this code, I get an error like:

```
 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://fileraja.com/download/?songURL=./Tamil/K/Kaththi_160kbps/Pakkam_Vanthu-StarMusiQ.Com.mp3. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

After some research, I have found that it's due to the `CORS` policy, so I tried adding the code `xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials",true);`, but it didn't help me.

How can I get rid of this error?

Answer (score 0):

> After some search i have found that its due to CORS policy...so i have tried adding the code...

You can't do **anything** client-side that will change the [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/) policy of the server. This is the point of the [SOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) and CORS: The server determines whether to allow any particular client to grab its content via ajax.

So unless `http://fileraja.com` are willing to add the relevant CORS headers at *their* end, you simply cannot do cross-origin requests to their domain with ajax. You might ask them, or ask if they offer a [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#JSONP) API (JSONP isn't subject to the SOP, because it's not ajax). Otherwise, you'll have to use a server of your own to proxy the request.

Comment: will it work if i add headers as @Knight rider suggests

Comment: @lovejs: Again: There's nothing you can do from the client that changes this. CORS has to be enabled **on the server**.

Comment: thanks ..but can you tell me how can i defined a header in ajax ??

Comment: @lovejs: Using the method you used in your question, [`setRequestHeader`](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-setrequestheader()-method). But note that the header you're trying to set in your question is a **response** header, not a request header (and if you were going to set it, you'd want the value `"true"`, not `true`).

Comment: i have used the method you suggested by using `xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials",true);` and using like `xhr.getResponseHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin')` but it throws me the same error

Comment: @lovejs: What part of "you can't do this on the client" do you not understand?!

Comment: will i be able to fetch the data if they provide jsonp facility

Comment: @lovejs: Yes, via JSONP (which is not ajax).

Answer (score 0):

This error is because of the CORS(Cross Origin Resource Sharing) Policy which does not allow requests that do not arise from the same origin. A header `Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *` can be set at the resource to allow all requests.

Other methods include JSONP as mentioned by T.J Crowder and the same server for proxy request.

This might be a good read [CORS and POST Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750696/how-to-get-a-cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors-post-request-working)

Comment: how can i set up a header in js ??

Comment: You cannot! the service or API that you call should have it in it's header..Change the Content type to JSONP in your call

Comment: i have added `xhr.setRequestHeader("jsonp")`..is it the way of doing this ??

Comment: Nopes, xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); oReq.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml"); Use: xmlhttp.setRequestHeader(key, value); READ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268673/set-a-request-header-in-javascript

Comment: Access-Control-Allow-Headers: * this  is written in Service  that you call, you have to write xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/jsonp");