# Add custom referer when fetching script via $.getscript()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I fetch script with

```
$.getScript("http://www.example.org/file.js");
```

However, the referer goes empty to that site. How can I use referer (can be antyhing) instead of empty referer ? Note: Using getscript is required, I cant use script src="".

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Send a header through AJAX to the target site to inform from where the call comes or any other data?

Answer (score 3):

You can send headers using directly `.ajax()`. From documentation:

> `jQuery.getScript()` is a shorthand Ajax function, which is equivalent to:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: 'script',
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

From here, we can use the `headers` setting and we get something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: 'script',
    headers: {'X-Alt-Referer': location.href },
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

**[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1269064/3648578)** can help you too.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this

```
function GetScript(url)
{
     $.getScript(url)
     .done(function(script, textStatus)
     {
         console.log( textStatus );
     })
     .fail(function( jqxhr, settings, exception ) {
         console.log(exception);
         return GetScript("http://www.example.org/file_2.js");
     });
}

GetScript("http://www.example.org/file.js");
```

Comment: Thanks, but where do you add referer in this function ?

Comment: I think you confused `deferred` with `referer`.