# HTML: Accept-Charset attribute and Accept attribute

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, http, character-encoding

I'm using angularJS, and when i try to set there `Accept-Charset` attribute i get: `Refused to set unsafe header "Accept-Charset"`, but when i set manually something like:

```
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'text/csv',
      'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain; charset=WIN-1251'
    }
```

all is ok

so... question)

Is there any difference between this two attributes?
or server will recognize my accept with charset, and i do not need `Accept-Charset` anymore?

Comment: read it, it will help you, i think: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20530085/4365315