# formspree using ajax not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, forms

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
                //Send email on form submission
                $('#contact-form').submit(function(e){
                    var name = $('#name').val();
                    var email = $('#email').val();
                    var message = $('#message').val();

                    if(name==='' || email==='' || message ===''){
                        return false
                    }
                    else{
                        e.preventDefault();
                        console.log("success");
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "https://formspree.io/xyz@gmail.com",
                            method: "POST",
                            data: {
                                name: name,
                                email: email,
                                message : message
                            },
                            dataType: "json" });
                    }
                })
            });
    </script>
```

**html form**

```
<form method="POST" id="contact-form">
                    <input type="text" name = "name" id="name" placeholder="Name" required>
                    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" required>
                    <textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="Message..." required></textarea>
                    <input type="submit" value="Send">
                </form>
```

I dont know what I am doing wrong, my data is not getting sent.
My formspree is all set up. Could someone help me with this. The issue looks small but just cant get it through

Comment: `unknown` errror, `undefined` information, what error you are getting ?

Comment: {"error": "Invalid \"Referrer\" header"}

Comment: There was no error, i was testing it using static html file and not a localhost server or any other for that matter. sorry:p

Comment: [Try with this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1269064/2815635)