# Get specific cookie and assign it as variable to make further request in headers

Tags: javascript, html

I have 4 cookies in my browser csrfToken, Auth, Email and lead.
I want make a post request to an endpoint /auth/admin. Here, I want to assign the csrfToken cookie value as header like 'X-CSRF-Token: token'.

How can i do that ?

Comment: What part of this are you having trouble with? Reading the cookie or setting the header?

Comment: [Get cookie by name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10730362/get-cookie-by-name)

Comment: [Set request header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268673/set-a-request-header-in-javascript)